# Visual Studio Code not formatting JavaScript correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, nodes

New to Visual Studio Code and Node here.

I wrote this line of code as part of a tutorial and run it through node.

```
const textOut = 'This is what we know about the avocado: ${textIn}.\nCreated on ${Date.now()}';
```

and the `${textIn}` and `${Date.now()}` do not generate the JavaScript as it should, but when I copy and paste the line directly from the tutorial

```
const textOut = `This is what we know about the avocado: ${textIn}.\nCreated on ${Date.now()}`;
```

it works perfectly. I did notice that on the line directly from the tutorial, the JavaScript portion is a different color but not on the one I wrote. Is there something I'm supposed to be doing to format JavaScript in Visual Studio Code?

[image]

I tried finding solutions online to no help.

Comment: It's a rather simple game of spot the difference. Once you have backticks `\`` and the other time you have single quotes `'`. That does matter in JavaScript. See [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: thank you bud. rookie mistake. my bad.